# Reading a data from BigQuery to Python in batches

Tags: python, google-bigquery, batch-processing

I have a table in BigQuery which needs to be processed with python code, this table is too big to fit into memory and to be preprocessed at once. Is there a way to read a BigQuery table in python with smaller batches, let's say 10000 rows at a time, and do the preprocessing in the loop?

Comment: Can you show us the query you used or tried, and your data structure (tables, columns, etc.)?